# Add new columns to comma delimited text file python

Tags: python

I am new to python and facing some problems.
I have a file with two columns separated by comma having numerical values (sample) -

```
2306,12017
2307,9416.6
2308,7378.5
2309,5781.4
```

and so on..

I am willing to have an output file somewhat like this -

```
bfe,2306,hgen,,12017
bfe,2307,hgen,,9416.6
bfe,2308,hgen,,7378.5
bfe,2309,hgen,,5781.4
```

and so on..

thanks in advance.

This is what I have tried so far,

```
data = open("myFile1.txt", "r").readlines()
output = ["%s,%s,%s,%s" % ("bfe",item.strip(),"hgen",item.strip()) for item in data]
f = open("output.txt", "w")
f.write("\n".join(output))
f.close()
```

Comment: have you tried using pandas?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question and provide appropriate information.

Comment: Show the code you have tried and exactly what problems you have, we are not going to write it for you but might be able to show where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = open("myFile1.txt", "r").readlines()
output = ["%s,%s,%s,%s" % ("bfe",item.split(",")[0],"hgen",item.split(",")[1]) for item in data]
f = open("output.txt", "w")
f.write("".join(output))
f.close()
```

Output.txt

```
bfe,2306,hgen,12017
bfe,2307,hgen,9416.6
bfe,2308,hgen,7378.5
bfe,2309,hgen,5781.4
```